# Kendo UI Datepicker ModelstateError with format : "yyyy"

Tags: razor, datepicker, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo Datepicker in my web application, just to choose the year of a date.

Everthing works fine until i try to submit my model, by using a submitbutton. My view calls the action, but it occurs the following ModelstateError and the date data field is null:

```
"The value '2010' is not valid for date."
```

The problem seem to be the format, used by the Datepicker.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.date)
      .Start(CalendarView.Decade)
      .Depth(CalendarView.Decade)
      .Format("yyyy"))  // <= this is the Problem .Format("MMMM yyyy") for example works
```

So, any ideas how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work with a regular Html.TextBoxFor when the value is 2010? Maybe ASP.NET MVC can't parse '2010' as a valid date.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I would like to use a Datepicker :/